# Failed to install twisted using pip on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Twisted install on ubuntu 22.04 is failing.

- apt-get install python2.7
- curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py && python2.7 get-pip.py
- pip install twisted.

```
Downloading Twisted-20.3.0.tar.bz2 (3.1 MB)
#11 18.36     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#11 18.36      command: /usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-MIySwm/twisted/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-MIySwm/twisted/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ljazb4
#11 18.36          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-MIySwm/twisted/
#11 18.36     Complete output (24 lines):
#11 18.36     DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
#11 18.36     Traceback (most recent call last):
#11 18.36       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#11 18.36       File "/tmp/pip-install-MIySwm/twisted/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
#11 18.36         setuptools.setup(**_setup["getSetupArgs"]())
#11 18.36       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
#11 18.36         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#11 18.36       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
#11 18.36         _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
#11 18.36       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 448, in __init__
#11 18.36         k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
#11 18.36       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
#11 18.36         self.finalize_options()
#11 18.36       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 740, in finalize_options
#11 18.36         ep(self)
#11 18.36       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 747, in _finalize_setup_keywords
#11 18.36         ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
#11 18.36       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
#11 18.36         return self.resolve()
#11 18.36       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
#11 18.36         module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
#11 18.36       File "/tmp/pip-install-MIySwm/twisted/.eggs/incremental-22.10.0-py2.7.egg/incremental/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
#11 18.36         from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any, TypeVar, Union, Optional, Dict
#11 18.36     ImportError: No module named typing
#11 18.36     ----------------------------------------
#11 18.36 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named typing`: `typing` is not a Python 2 module. So you're installing Python 3 code for Python 2.

Comment: Why do you not install Twisted with Python 3?

Comment: Note that the `python-pip` package would have installed `pip2` for you. Then again, I strongly recommend *not* using Python 2 anymore; it's been unmaintained since 2020.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, how?

Comment: We have replaced python2.7 by python3